# Unity 2D - How to play death animation prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have created a prefab with animation from sprite sheet, which I want to be played when the Player dies. I checked if the prefab is working by dragging it in the Scene, and it is correctly playing every frame of the sprite sheet in a loop endlessly.

Now I want to play this prefab when the Player dies, and after it ends to destroy it, but so far I am only able to place it where the player dies, and it stays there forever. Also there are some errors when that happens.

Here is the death script:

```
 public class DmgByCollisionEnemy : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject deathAnimation;

    void Die() {
        deathAnimation = (GameObject) Instantiate(deathAnimation, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        //Destroy(deathAnimation);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

I set the deathAnimation by dragging a prefab in the Unity interface.

The error I am getting when the `Die()` method fires is

```
UnassignedReferenceException: The variable deathAnimation of DmgByCollisionEnemy has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the deathAnimation variable of the DmgByCollisionEnemy script in the inspector.
```

So how can I do that properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to add simple destroy script to Your death animation object that destroys object after time or trigger it in animation ([Unity Manual: Using Animation Events](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html)). When you instantiate object it will appear on desired position and it will be destroied regardless to "main" object.

Destroy Script like this:

```
void DestroyMyObject() 
{ 
   Destroy(gameObject); 
}
```

Script to run after time:

```
void Start() 
{
    Invoke ("DestroyMyObject", 1f);
}

void DestroyMyObject()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Spawn script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

   public class SpawnExtra : MonoBehaviour {

   public GameObject deathAnimation;

   public static SpawnExtra instance;

   void Start () 
   {
        instance = this;
   }

   public void SpawnDeathAnimation(Vector3 position)
   {
        Instantiate (deathAnimation, position, Quaternion.identity);
   }
}
```

And you can use it when you want to spawn additional object like this:

```
SpawnExtra.instance.SpawnDeathAnimation (transform.position);
```

Now you have to add gameobject e.g ExtrasController, add script on it and you can spawn whatever you want. Remember to drag&drop animation prefab in inspector.

Comment: but how do I make a timer-like code? a for-loop wont work for this

Comment: There are two usefull methods. Corutines and Invoke. I recomend you to use Invoke. Like this: Invoke("DestroyMyObject", 1f); - this code will run you function DestroyMyObject after 1 second. Made some edits to better show example.

Comment: that works just awesome, but I am still getting this error (or warning? its with a red (!) symbol) - "The variable deathAnimation of DmgByCollisionEnemy" has not been assigned. This is the public object, which I define by dragging the animation prefab in the Unity UI

Comment: Did you make drag&drop on play mode? Its most common problem to remember that you have to make changes NOT on play mode :) Just asking to be sure.

Comment: nope, its not on play mode, I think the problem is because the prefab is being cloned with the Instantiate method, but I dont know exactly how to fix it

Comment: There is a way i using to spawn exta object. You can ma a script like this and spawn object regardless to cloned objects. I'll make an update to answer.

Comment: Thanks everything worked awesome, but the errors were because I had this Damage script on the Bullets as well, and they didn't had the Prefab dragged&dropped in them, fixed it now